# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config as array in .../framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I've created a simple User Repository class in Laravel that will handle all CRUD functionalities.

Everything works fine, but when I try to unit test it with phpunit, it all breaks apart.

I'm running the latest development version of [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop), I understand this isn't a stable release but I'm confused whether this is a laravel bug or am I doing something wrong.

When running phpunit, I get [this huge error output.](http://jpst.it/vblq)

The classes I have are

**Model Role**

```
namespace Shazzam\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

**Role Repository**

```
namespace Shazzam\Repositories;

use \Shazzam\Models\Role;

class RoleRepository
{

    /**
     * @param array $args
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create($args)
    {
        $role = new Role($args);

        return $role->save();
    }
}
```

**RoleRepository Test**

```
use Shazzam\Repositories\RoleRepository;

class RoleRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public $repo;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->repo = new RoleRepository;
    }

    public function test_it_creates_a_new_role()
    {
        $role['name'] = "NewRole";

        $this->assertTrue($this->repo->create($role));
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you see that I'm doing anything wrong. I'd really like to keep working on the dev version of Laravel. Thanks.

Edit 
1- Removed array typehint in the RoleRepository create method. Updated Title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call the base class setUp method:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
```

Comment: THANK YOU! (I was using Config above parent::setUp(), doh')

Answer (score 5):

For me it works such as:

```
public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        // Create DB in memory!
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        DB::beginTransaction();

        Session::start();

        factory('App\Models\User')->create();        
    }
```

Important: *parent::tearDown()* must be below *DB::rollBack()* in my case, otherwise it doesn't work!

```
  public function tearDown() {

            DB::rollBack();
            parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RoleRepository::create() is being passed a `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config` object, not an `array`. Take away your typehint of `array` in the signature and it should run.

Comment: Just did it and ran phpunit again, still same huge error output. Updated the output http://justpaste.it/ij98 
I'm really starting to think it is something with the framework when running through phpunit, like some of the database configurations may not be initialized correctly... Spent quite a lot of time debugging this but nothing yet :/. Thanks thought.

Comment: Bugger, I was certain that was it. If you skip past the PHPUnit stacktrace, you can see it's line 18 of RoleReposity - the save() call - that's causing the error. It's really not liking the Config class. I'm not a user of Laravel, are you in control of what gets passed to create()? If so, you may need to pass it an array, rather than the Config class.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem because my test file was extending `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, so I changed it to extend `Tests\TestCase` instead. And my tests started running just fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another case:

Do not access to application in service `__destruct` method as application could be already terminated when service is destructing